# MySQL How to Index a JSON array?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, indexing, query-optimization

I have a JSON field with one-dimensional array. In fact, in this field I have a list of some IDs, like this:

```
[347470, 162063, 17315, 346852, 174776, 295865, 7833, 136813]
```

In my queries I refer this field like this:

```
... AND JSON_CONTAINS(`users_actions`, 174776)=0
```

My question is: should I create an index for this field, and if so - which exactly index should I use?

Comment: Do you mean [like this](https://mysqlserverteam.com/indexing-json-documents-via-virtual-columns/)?

Comment: It's worth noting that Postgres does a fantastic job of this on `ARRAY,`, `HSTORE` and `JSON` columns. MySQL not so much.

Comment: @tadman I don't think that's applicable

Comment: I don't think there's a way to index this in MySQL. You would be better off normalizing the schema.

Comment: @tadman As far as I understand, stored generated columns are good if I'd have a multi-dimensional array in my JSON field

Comment: @tadman: agree with Barmar, that technique works for JSON objects, not for arrays.

Comment: IMO, anytime you reference a JSON column in a WHERE clause, it's a red flag. You should normalize the data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are running a very recent version of MySQL (8.0.17 or higher), you can use a [Multi-valued index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued), which was designed exactly for that purpose:

> A multi-valued index is a secondary index defined on a column that stores an array of values.
>
> [...]
>
> Multi-valued indexes are intended for indexing `JSON` arrays.
>
> [...]
>
> The optimizer uses a multi-valued index to fetch records when the following functions are specified in a `WHERE` clause: `MEMBER OF()`, `JSON_CONTAINS()`, `JSON_OVERLAPS()`.

Assuming that your json array is stored in column `myjs` of table `mytable`, you can create the index like so:

```
CREATE INDEX myidx 
ON mytable ( (CAST(myjs AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)) );
```

Comment: How do we index an array which contains objects ?

Comment: @SudhirN: this type of index supports scalar values only, hence so far we [can't do that in MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/6a-V4ZOj): *Cannot store an array or an object in a scalar key part of the index*

Comment: so we cant have an index if its an array of objects

Comment: @SudhirN: no - as you can see in the fiddle that I linked in my comment.

Comment: I see... is that your tool, dbfiddle ? nice would love to see it evolve